# How to output char array in c

Tags: c

Newbiee here, 
I am trying to scan characters from a txt file and output it to another txt file. I think my problem is conversion specifiers converting int to char so my result is weird characters. Thanks for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NROW 676
#define FILEIN "lettercombo.txt"
#define FILEOUT "lettercomboout.txt"

int main(void) {
//Variables
int i;
char combo [NROW];
FILE *lcombo;
FILE *lcomboout;

//Writes output file or overwrites previous one
lcomboout = fopen(FILEOUT,"w");


// Open file and read data into array
lcombo = fopen(FILEIN,"r");
for (i=0; i<677; i++)
    fscanf(lcombo,"%c",&combo[i]);

for (i=0; i<677; i++)
        fprintf(lcomboout,"%c \n",combo[i]);




return 0;
}
```

Update post:
I forgot to add the input file in the same folder. I appreciate the help, it works :)

Comment: Please give(as update post) an example of the output file to be expected and  input file.

Comment: You are reading (via fscanf) integers from input into "combo", which is defined as an array of char... if you want to read "chars" instead of "integer", then change "%i" to "%c".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix like this:

```
#define NROW 676 // 26*26 : [A-Z] * [A-Z]
//...
//Variables
int i;
char combo[NROW][2];
//...abridgement
for (i=0; i<NROW; i++)
    fscanf(lcombo," %2c", combo[i]);//fscanf(lcombo," %c%c", &combo[i][0], &combo[i][1]);

for (i=0; i<NROW; i++)
        fprintf(lcomboout, "%c%c\n", combo[i][0], combo[i][1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

change

```
fscanf(lcombo,"%i",&combo[i]);
```

to

```
fscanf(lcombo,"%c",&combo[i]);
```

as you scan chars.

change

```
fprintf(lcomboout,"%c \n",&combo[i]);
```

to

```
fprintf(lcomboout,"%c \n",combo[i]);
```

`%c` takes a value, not address.

and use `fclose` to close the file.

---

**UPD**

The code reads `NROW` chars, not `NROW` lines, change to

```
for (i=0; EOF != fscanf(lcombo,"%c",&combo[i]); ++i);
```

or use `%s` to read lines, it is good manner to check return value of `scanf/fscanf`.

And you can keep how many chars has been successfully read. For example:

```
int len;
...
for (len=0; EOF != fscanf(lcombo,"%c",&combo[len]); ++len);
for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    fprintf(lcomboout,"%c \n",combo[i]);
```

---

1. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: thanks, I have applied these changes but still get the weird encoding in my output file with characters like @, $% and spaces.

Comment: @comphonia Can you post your input? Is the file utf-8 or other encoding?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 errors in your code.

- The first one, you figured it out by yourself.

  `fscanf(lcombo,"%i",&combo[i]);`

  should be

  `fscanf(lcombo,"%c",&combo[i]);`
- The second one is a basic mistake. When you read from the array, you
  pass arguments by value, not by reference:

  `fprintf(lcomboout,"%c \n",&combo[i]);`

  should be

  `fprintf(lcomboout,"%c \n", combo[i]);`.

Both of those mistakes would be easily identified if you had read the warnings sent by the compiler:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:20:19: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
     fscanf(lcombo,"%i",&combo[i]);
                   ^
main.c:23:27: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
         fprintf(lcomboout,"%c \n",&combo[i]);
                       ^
```

Also, it is a good principle is to use the flag `-Wall` (meaning **W**arning:**all**) to compile your code, for example: `gcc -Wall my_program.c -o my_program`. A lot more warnings will raise.

Comment: thanks, ill use this flag for future code, I did it well at first but forgot to put the input in the same folder. i appreciate it.